# Error with character mapping when conversing filesystem::path to string or printing them with MSVC

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

I'm using VS2022 and wrote the following program:

```cpp
void rena::HUFO::_traversal_dir_write_to_hlist( const std::filesystem::path& dir ){
    for ( auto it : std::filesystem::directory_iterator( dir ) )
    {
        auto fp = it.path(); // file path
        if ( std::filesystem::is_directory( fp ) )
        {
            _traversal_dir_write_to_hlist( fp );
        } // dir found, traversal it
        else
        {
            if ( fp == this -> _hufopath )
            {
                continue;
            } // ignore HUFO itself
            DEBUG_MSG( fp );
            HASHOBJ temp;
            temp.fp = std::filesystem::relative( fp , this -> _pdpath );
            this -> _hlist.push_back( temp );
        } // write relative path to _hlist
    }
    return;
}
```

It works perfectly until I reached a file which its name is `FM_(｀・ω・´)ｼｬｷｰﾝ1(1秒).ogg`, the program called abort in runtime.

I caught the exception and it is `There are no characters to which this Unicode character can be mapped in the multibyte target code page`. (I guess because I use Chinese version and the original message was `在多字节的目标代码页中，没有此 Unicode 字符可以映射到的字符`.) Same exception was caught when I tried to do `fp.string()`.

And I also found out that this exception was caught only when I tried to print this filename. When I deleted this `DEBUG_MSG( fp );`, nothing happened, no exception was caught.

I tried to use `wcout` and `wstring`, but they didn't solve my problem. No more exception was caught, but the output was broken.

The output was (with `cout` and `string and exception catch):

```
"...\\camera.wav"
Error occured when traversaling directory "...":
在多字节的目标代码页中，没有此 Unicode 字符可以映射到的字符。
Error path output unavaliable.
Skip the current file.
"...\\FM_アイテムゲット11(1秒).ogg"
"...\\FM_アイテムゲット2(1秒).ogg"
"...\\FM_アイテムゲット3(1秒).ogg"
... (other files)
```

And with `wcout` and `wstring` it was like:

```
"...\\camera.wav"
"...\\FM_(
```

I also tried to use `.u8string()`, but the output was also full of mojibakes.

I would like to know (if anyboby knows) why this happened and how I can solve it, print the path successfully and with no nonsense.

Comment: *"when I tried to do `fp.string()`."* -- This expression does not appear in your code.

Comment: *"I also found out that this exception was caught only when I tried to print this filename."* -- This is good, because it means you can reduce your code to just this. You shouldn't need all that processing to demonstrate the error. Try for something simpler. Assuming you cannot replicate this with a hardcoded file name (which would be better), create a directory containing just the problematic file and reduce your function to something like `void dir_write(const std::filesystem::path& dir) { auto fp = std::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir).begin().path(); std::cout << fp.string(); }`.

Comment: *"I also tried to use `.u8string()`"* -- Why? Windows uses UTF-16, not UTF-8. (See [documentation of `path::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string): *"This is the case on Windows, where `wchar_t` is 16 bit and the native encoding is UTF-16."*)

Comment: @JaMit Yeah I've just reduced my code and made it as short as possible, but the problem was still there. But the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string) inspired me. I added `_setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_WTEXT)` at the begining of the program, and always use `std::wcerr` to print wchars, and it solved the problem.